# How to get the terminal content during the VS Code extension development

Tags: typescript, terminal, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VS code extension and I meet a question. That is, how to get the current terminal content? My `activate` function's singleton is as follows and I want to get the current terminal content when I activate my text editor command.

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('xxx', (editor) => { 
        // code here
    });
}
```

I'm not familiar with the typescript language and spend lots of time searching this question. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I found some activation functions about the Terminal, such as `vscode.windows.createTerminal()`, but I failed to extract the content from the Terminal. And I also tried other const variables like `vscode.windows.terminals` whose return value was not what I want either.